# How to add a column to existing table in flask

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

Done as follows but no column is added.

#### Migrate database

`python manage.py db migrate`

#### Edit migrations/versions/{version}_.py

```
def upgrade():
    from alembic import op
    op.add_column('table_name', Column('column_name', INTEGER) )
```

#### Update schema

`python manage.py db upgrade`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that alembic stores version in table called `alembic_version`, and once `{version}` is in alembic_version, then nothing happens.
The solution is to create a new migration script and do migrate again.